# Using a for loop to iterate through a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am attempting to write a loop to iterate through a 2D array and sum each sub-array.

So far my code is as follows:

```
int[][] data = { { 10, 20 }, { 20, 10 }, { 50, 60 }, { 45, 20 }, { 10, 35 }, { 25, 16 } };
int[] sumOfArrays = new int[5];

    for (int[] i : data) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int x : i) {
            sum =+ x;
        }
        sumOfArrays[i] = sum;
    }

    System.out.println(sumOfArrays);
```

This is not possible due to a type mismatch: (i) int[] - int

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems here.  Let's start with the one that bit you the hardest.

```
for (int[] i : data) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int x : i) {
        sum =+ x;
    }
    sumOfArrays[i] = sum;
}
```

Inside the context of these nested loops, `i` refers to an `int[]` reference, so you can't use it to index into anything.

In general, when dealing with foreach loops, you *generally lose the ability to index into them*, so you should use caution when you're attempting to do so.

To get that, you have to introduce a new variable.  Also be sure to flip your assignment; you want `+=` instead of `=+`, since the former is just assignment to a guaranteed positive value.

```
int idx = 0;
for (int[] i : data) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int x : i) {
        sum += x;
    }
    sumOfArrays[idx++] = sum;
}
```

Next, your array is one element too short - you have six rows but you only allocate room for 5.  Fix that size and then the above code will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to treat `i` as if it were an index, but it's a value -- the `int[]` row you're currently on.

You can keep a separate `index` variable that is incremented at the end of the `i` for loop.

```
int index = 0;
for (int[] i : data) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int x : i) {
        sum += x;  // +=, not =+
    }
    sumOfArrays[index] = sum;
    index++;
}
```

An alternative would be to switch to a "standard" for loop, so you have the index variable defined as part of the for loop, getting the `int[]` yourself.

Either way, you'll need to use [`Arrays.toString` to print the contents of `sumOfArrays`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4) at the end of your code.

Additionally, the length of `sumOfArrays` doesn't match the length of `data`, so you'll get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.  Try

```
int[] sumOfArrays = data.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int[][] data = { { 10, 20 }, { 20, 10 }, { 50, 60 }, { 45, 20 }, { 10, 35 }, { 25, 16 } };
    int[] sumOfArrays = new int[data.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int x : data[i]) {
            sum += x;
        }
        sumOfArrays[i] = sum;
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sumOfArrays));
```

Comment: Ah @Makoto explained it already, no need for me explaining what went wrong then :)

Comment: Edited, didn't saw that you did =+ while it needs to be +=

Comment: This is **not** the exact same code: the for loop is changed to a regular for loop, with the value used as an index into the original 2D array and the new sum array

Comment: This doesn't make the answer any better.  All it is is a code dump.  It doesn't *explain* anything.

Comment: @Makoto was going to add an explanation, but then saw that you already posted yours, I even said so in the first comment on this answer...